# Media Player for android only force quit with nexus 5 and say "fatal signal 11"

Tags: android

I am writing a media player to play m3u8 URL. I can make the player which play well with other like samsung device and even nexus 10.

However, when I test with nexus 5, it always force quit and report "fatal signal 11". From debug mode, I see that the media player cannot go to "onPrepared()".

Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post the `adb logcat` logs.

Comment: logcat: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 23294